# Search for text, print a message about it, and then return cursor to original position

Tags: search, motion

I want to write an Elisp command that searches for a specific string in the backward direction, pauses the cursor there for a second, echoes a message about that occurrence, and then returns the cursor back to its original position. The purpose of the command is to *examine the contents surrounding* the search string. My text is structured like below:

```
\begin{myverse}
line one of verse
line two of verse ॥ 3.2 ॥ \\
\end{myverse}
\vspace{2mm}
Lots of text
below
over multiple
lines
cursor here
```

If my cursor is at the last line (`cursor here`), I would like the Elisp function to search backwards for the first occurrence of the text `॥`, pause for a bit so that I can read the number (**3.2**), and then return the cursor back to its previous position. I have the following command:

```lisp
    (defun fn ()
      "Retrieve verse number"
      (interactive)
      (setq test-str "॥")
      (save-excursion
        (search-backward test-str)
        (sit-for 1)))
```

How can this command be enhanced so that it that prints the verse number in the echo area (i.e. where I type `M-x fn`)?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want this. This matches the text between the markers and makes it a message in the minibuffer when it is found.

```
(defun fn ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (when (re-search-backward "॥\\(.*\\)॥" nil t)
      (message (match-string 1))
      (sit-for 1))))
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks @John

Answer (score 1):

You can get behavior similar to what you want by just using backward *incremental* search (`C-r`, or `C-M-r` for regexp-searching). That takes you to the first search hit (and you can repeat the key to move to subsequent hits). This lets you see the search hit in context, which I guess is what your aim is.

You can then just use `C-g` to cancel searching -- that returns the cursor to the starting point.

(If you instead want to leave the cursor at a search hit, just use `RET` when you get to that hit.)

Answer (score 0):

Your Q is a bit mixed up as at the end of it you've asked for something not related to the title, but all good.

Looking at your text structure wouldn't it not be a better idea to search backwards for text enclosed by your special format char?

eg  ॥ FINDME ॥

And this is where you can have some fun reading the man page for [re-search-backward](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Search.html)

Of course, there are edge cases to sort out at a later date eg starting the search while inside your special grouping. But that's a separate issue for now.